# Is there a Map Type selector available with google_maps_flutter Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

With google_maps_flutter it is possible to display multiple map type (satellite / map ...)

Is there any widget available to selection the map type ?

Answer (score 0):

> "With google_maps_flutter it is possible to display multiple map type (satellite / map ...)"

Yes., The Google maps widget accepts the following as valid types:

/// Do not display map tiles.
none

/// Normal tiles (traffic and labels, subtle terrain information).
normal,

/// Satellite imaging tiles (aerial photos)
satellite,

/// Terrain tiles (indicates type and height of terrain)
terrain,

/// Hybrid tiles (satellite images with some labels / overlays)
hybrid

> "Is there any widget available to selection the map type ?"

Not at the moment, but you can create it easily :)